# How to stack several pandas DataFrames in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

Since I have multiple pandas DataFrames, I want to run the .stack() method on all of them using a for loop. Other methods like labeling columns and setting indexes work, but for some reason the stack method doesn't lead to any changes:

```
for df in [df1, df2, df3, df4]:
    df = df.stack()
```

Result:

```
print(df1.head())

        Q1 1990  Q2 1990  Q3 1990   ...     Q2 2018  Q3 2018  Q4 2018
EC                                  ...                              
C13840      NaN      NaN      NaN   ...         NaN      NaN      NaN
C28525      NaN      NaN      NaN   ...     8480.00  8125.00      NaN
C06541      NaN      NaN      NaN   ...         NaN      NaN      NaN
C51345      NaN      NaN      NaN   ...       13.75    15.00      NaN
C44265      NaN      NaN      NaN   ...      141.90   129.54   133.44
```

Expected result:

```
print(df1.head(10))

EC             
C13840  Q1 1990   NaN
        Q2 1990   NaN
        Q3 1990   NaN
        Q4 1990   NaN
        Q1 1991   NaN
        Q2 1991   NaN
        Q3 1991   NaN
        Q4 1991   NaN
        Q1 1992   NaN
        Q2 1992   NaN
        ...
        ...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify: a) what means "doesn't work", b) your expected output. Can you create [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating your problem?

Comment: iiuc he wants to apply `stack` to all the dataframes but in the loop the `stack` is not retained by the original dfs

Comment: Added an example for expected vs actual result now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign output to new list od `Series`, because `stack` not working inplace:

```
dfs = [df.stack() for df in [df1, df2, df3, df4]]
```

And then if need assign back:

```
df1, df2, df3, df4 = dfs
```

Or join together:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Comment: yes but the originals are still not modified which is what I believe he wants, this just makes a new list

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to modify your `dfs` in place however `stack` is not an inplace operator but returns a new `df` as the output

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5,6], 'b': [7,8]})


new_dfs = list(map(pd.DataFrame.stack, [df, df1]))
```

Comment: Interesting solution. :)